# El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado, java, netbeans

Tags: java, jframe, ftp, interface, netbeans-11

Tengo el siguiente archivo en esta parte del proyecto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con la idea de llegar a ese archivo, agrego el siguiente metodo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Claro, este es el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad, es que no entiendo porque.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vayamos por partes:

- Tienes el archivo con los .java, pero eso no es lo que se ejecuta. El IDE te genera los .class compilando los .java y te los mete en una carpeta. Eso será lo que se ejecute. Según la herramienta y la configuración que uses para la compilación, igual te copia el *fileList.txt* allí o no.
- En todo caso, aunque esté, las rutas de archivo son relativas al directorio de ejecución, no al directorio donde está la clase<sup>1</sup>. El [javadoc de java.io.File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String)) dice:

  > By default the classes in the java.io package always resolve relative pathnames against the current user directory. This directory is named by the system property user.dir, and is typically the directory in which the Java virtual machine was invoked.

  Es decir, si haces *System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"))*, esa es la ruta donde te busca el fichero si no le pones una ruta absoluta.
- Además, igual empaquetas todo el proyecto en un .jar y aunque exista el *fileList.txt* en el jar, no estará como fichero en la ubicación de las clases.

En general, si quieres "empaquetar" un fichero con tu aplicación, dentro de las mismas clases, vale más leerlo con *getResourceAsStream()*; por ejemplo *TextServer.class.getResourceAsStream("fileList.txt");*. Nota que eso es un *InputStream*, no un *File*, así que igual necesitas usar otros métodos para acceder a él (y no podrás modificarlo). Repito, asegúrate que la herramienta de compilación/build copie el fichero al compilar la aplicación.

Si quieres usar un *File*, no lo pongas entre tus clases, y especifica la ruta correctamente, ya sea de forma absoluta o relativa (pista: puedes crear un *File* con la ruta y hacer un *getAbsolutePath()* aunque el fichero no exista).

<sup>1</sup> De hecho la clase, para Java, no está en un directorio; está en el classpath y se identifica por su package.

Comment: Efectivamente, al final era que no podia encontrar el archivo porque no accedia a la carpeta o porque no estaba ahi el archivo. Lo solucione sacando ese archivo de la carpeta y poniendolo en la raiz. Muchas gracias por la indo.